# OpenCV - cvBlob

Tags: opencv, blob

Please explain the code below:

```
 struct CvTrack  
 {
   CvID id; ///< Track identification number. 
   CvLabel label; ///< Label assigned to the blob related to this track.

   unsigned int minx; ///< X min.
   unsigned int maxx; ///< X max.
   unsigned int miny; ///< Y min.
   unsigned int maxy; ///< y max.

   CvPoint2D64f centroid; ///< Centroid.

   unsigned int lifetime; ///< Indicates how much frames the object has been in scene.
   unsigned int active; ///< Indicates number of frames that has been active from last inactive period.
   unsigned int inactive; ///< Indicates number of frames that has been missing.
   unsigned int speed;
 };
```

What is the purpose of the variables `active` and `inactive` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the question to be regarding object tracking and the comments in your code pretty much answers your question.

Assume you are tracking a pink ball rolling on a table.

**Inactive** is the number of frames over which the ball is occluded and remains invisible to the camera.

**Active** is the number of consecutive frames over which the ball is visible to camera.

If ball is continuously visible and suddenly becomes invisible in the current frame, the following will happen:

```
lifetime++;
inactive++;
active = 0;
```

This [matlab post](http://in.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/motion-based-multiple-object-tracking.html) will give you a better understanding about maintaining track of the object being tracked.

Comment: **Shan** , What causes this variable to increment?, whether it can be as if the two objects closer and merge into one that is missing from the frame, or inactive increment when object not detected current frame...

Comment: Both the scenarios you mentioned would increase the inactive count.
In case-1: There will be 2 tracks for the 2 balls, so if it merges into one, one of the tracks will increment the inactive variable. This is just a special case of case-2. 

_Inactive variable increases when the tracked object is not detected in current frame_.